# Lua Right mousebutton clicker

Tags: lua, logitech-gaming-software

I hope my title is okay.

I have this working script for Ghub that when mousebutton 4 is pressed, it spams Left mousebutton:

```
function OnEvent(event, arg)
   if(event == "PROFILE_ACTIVATED") then
      EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true);
   elseif(event == "PROFILE_DEACTIVATED") then
   end
   if  IsMouseButtonPressed(4)then
      repeat
         PressMouseButton(1)
         Sleep(1)
         ReleaseMouseButton(1)
      until not IsMouseButtonPressed(4)
   end
end
```

How can I add the same function in the same script but for rightclick spam when mousebutton 5 is pressed?

Comment: Is it true that buttons 4 and 5 will never be pressed simultaneously?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Just add one more `if` block similar to the one you already have:

```
function OnEvent(event, arg)
   if event == "PROFILE_ACTIVATED" then
      EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true)
   end
   if IsMouseButtonPressed(4) then
      repeat
         PressMouseButton(1) -- LMB
         Sleep(1)
         ReleaseMouseButton(1)
      until not IsMouseButtonPressed(4)
   end
   if IsMouseButtonPressed(5) then
      repeat
         PressMouseButton(3) -- RMB
         Sleep(1)
         ReleaseMouseButton(3)
      until not IsMouseButtonPressed(5)
   end
end
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I swear I tried something similar, but I guess my error was in line 14 and 16, I had a 2 instead of a 3.